# Yii pack generated js code to external file

Tags: javascript, yii, clientscript

Some yii widgets generates js code (for ajax update or etc.) and this code yii puts to the end of the page.
Simular behavior have yii's ClientScript::registerScript() function, i want yii to put this code to external files, and link them in the document. what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Write all the scripts to a file and then do `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('YOUR_FILE_NAME');`

Comment: But what about autogenerated code by widgets?

Answer (score 0):

There are already some extension which might do this, see http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=css

[This one](https://github.com/mikehaertl/packagecompressor) looks nice. However I could not give you a recommendation because I have never used any of them. We have written our own extension for this purpose.